# Codeigniter submit form when accessing URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, codeigniter

I have a form that works perfectly when I click the submit button.
What I want is that if I add parameters in the URL, it submits the form automatically when accessing the URL.

My form looks like this :

```
<form id="form_group_data" name="form_group_data"  method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo site_url('admin/group/add')?>">
   <p>
   <div class="form-body">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="name">Name<span class="required"> * </span></label>   
         <div class="col-md-4">
            <input id="name" class="form-control" type="text" name="name" required="required" value="">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="firstname">Firstname<span class="required"> * </span></label>   
         <div class="col-md-4">
            <input id="firstname" class="form-control" type="text" name="firstname" required="required" value="">
         </div>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Ajouter" class="btn blue"/>
      <button type="button" class="btn default" onclick="window.location='<?php echo site_url('admin/group')?>'">Annuler</button>
   </div>
   </p>
</form>
```

If I fill the fields manually and submit it, it works. Now I can enter this URL and it fills the fields via the parameters in the URL, but I'd like it to submit it automatically too, without clicking on the submit button.

Example URL that fills fields automatically : https://test.ch/admin/user/insert/John/Lennon

Is it possible ? With JQuery maybe ?

Comment: remove the man in the middle -> the form and append the data to the db directly

Answer (score 0):

- check if the url parameters exist
- if yes, assuming the form is filled with the data from url submit it using jquery

Put this code just before the closing body tag

```
<?php 
if(isset(your_url_parameters)) // check if all parameters exist in url
{ ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#form_group_data").submit(); //submit the form
    });
</script>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ability for fill out the form - you are setting this url -  then you could also send this data to a different url that already handles the form submit action. So, rather than trying to round about submit this form after filling the data, point it to the action url `admin/group/add/other/params/here` in the first place with these parameters and in that controller, check for these parameters. Note however, that in this case you are side stepping csrf protection and opening a potential vulnerability as such. You'd be best off to post to this endpoint with the csrf token as well as the data to post, if you have that protection turned on.

Alternatively, you can use the controller for this form to check if the parameters are set in the url. You should be able to check for the parameters and if they are set (and pass your validation if you are going for that) do what you normally do on a form submit.

```
if (isset($this->uri->segment(4)) && isset($this->uri->segment(5)) {
    // Do the work here - add to db, etc. Alternatively call the function 
    // that is supposed to do the work and pass these parameters in some way.
    $this->load->model("my_user_model");
    $this->my_user_model->add_user($this->uri->segment(4), $this->uri->segment(5));
    redirect("success/url");
}
```

This is JUST an example. You need to sanitize and validate any form data you deal with, so in this case, either the my_user_model->add_user needs to do that, or ideally you'd do that before the model using CI's form validation library.

I'd highly recommend taking a look at the [form validation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html?highlight=validation#overview) docs as a good example for how forms and submitted data can be handled using CI's built in functionality.